# Android video capture intent crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, video-capture

I need to record a video within the application using the intent. I think the code is correct, however when I do start the image stops and the file gets 0Bytes. I let down the code I'm using.

The first function called:

```
protected void makeVideo() {
        //create new Intent

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);  // create a file to save the video
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set the video image quality to high

        // start the Video Capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

getOutputMediaFile function:

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        //      Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        //      File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Constants.ALBUM.AlbumInPhone);
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), Constants.ALBUM.AlbumInPhone);
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d(Constants.ALBUM.AlbumInPhone, "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        File x = mediaFile;
        int y=0;
        y=1;

        return mediaFile;
    }

private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }
```

and:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                //              Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String uri = fileUri.getPath();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(uri)){
                    Log.v(TAG, "Could not get video");
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "video: " + uri);
                    if(BebeDataBaseManager.addVideoToAlbum(this, uri, albumId)){
                        Log.v(TAG, "video: added");
                        this.cursor.requery();
                    } else {
                        Log.v(TAG, "video: not added");
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the video capture
            } else {
                // Video capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
...
```

I'm doing something wrong?